# Why isn't my logged-in segue working?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I need to bypass the signup/login screen if the user is already logged in. Absolutely nothing happens. Printing to the log works, so I know the problem isn't the viewDidLoad() function, and I also know that PFUser.currentUser() is NOT nil. It is also not the segue, as the same segue is used on the login button, and it works in that event. So why isn't it working automatically?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        println(PFUser.currentUser())
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToMenu", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried performing the segue later in the lifecycle? There's a possibility that the viewcontroller and/or segue are not finished loading when this code is executed. Try the segue from viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear instead.

Comment: Hmm I've always had luck doing this kind of thing in the viewDidAppear, because the view hierarchy isn't always fully loaded until then. If you've checked that the identifier is typed correctly and you're sure the code is executing (thrown a breakpoint inside the if to make sure?) I'd have to see more code!

Comment: is `jumpToMenu` actually defined on this VC (is the login button you refer to on this VC)?

Comment: Nope, it's defined on a different View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and it will work.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToMenu", sender: self)
}}
```

The trick is to use viewDidAppear. Your code will not work in viewDidLoad because the code runs just before the view loads because of which all the segues are not in place. Hope this helps!